# Spring-Boot :: Converting spring context xml to Java Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to some old spring stuff in spring context xml to latest spring boot. I prefer to make the best of Java Configuration and Annotations rather than the old Xmls. I was not sure about how to handle the below bean definition snippet. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
<property name="properties">
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter"
        factory-method="getProperties">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <ref bean="dbDataSource" />
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg value="DOMAIN_CONFIG" />
                <constructor-arg value="CONFIG_NAME" />
                <constructor-arg value="CONFIG_VALUE" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Seems like people tend to believe SO is for doing their homework...

Answer (score 0):

Easy guys. I knew it was hasty thing. Anyway heres the code in terms of Java Config.

Intent of the code is to load database config on startup of a Spring boot application. I am yet to test it though..

```
@Bean
public static DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration(DataSource datasource) {
    return new DatabaseConfiguration(datasource, "DOMAIN_CONFIG", "CONFIG_NAME", "CONFIG_VALUE");
}

@Bean
public static Properties configurationConverter(DataSource datasource) {
    return ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(databaseConfiguration(datasource));
}

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer(DataSource datasource) {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setSystemPropertiesModeName("SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE");
    configurer.setProperties(configurationConverter(datasource));
    return configurer;
}
```